# Why use the th element instead of td element?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm reading up on the differences between the HTML `th` and `th` elements used in `<table>`

According to http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/f/blfaqthvstd.htm , the `th` element `defines the current cell as a table header.`

It then goes on to say that some browsers will render the `th` element differently (defined by the browser) but the article then advises not to style the TH ourselves (via CSS I assume).

I'm completely confused by this; It is suggesting that to use `th` element gives us no design control and has no value/importance...

I know some elements are older and some become obsolete, but I find no mention that the `th` element is depreciated nor can I see any value in it.

Would some one let me know if I've miss-understood please. Does Google read TH differently (again, my research shows nothing), does the `th` element help the browser to render the table, or is it just an option to use if we want to?

Comment: Well except for the `<th>` being rendered in bold, which most people will change anyway, I would say it is only an OCD thing.

Comment: This question is pretty old but I think it's worth rebutting the previous comment, that the value of HTML isn't from its default styling provided by the browser, but from its value in "marking up" information (semantics), whether it's for Google/search engines to categorize things, or arguably more importantly, accessibility technologies that don't look at the visual styling at all. A table header vs. a table cell has meaning that's useful for non-visual users.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) *Why use the `th` element instead of `td` element?*

Semantics, it won't make any difference to you whether you use `td` instead of `th`, well, it will get your work done happily, but, to differentiate them, we use `th`, `thead`, `tfoot` etc, it's like we can use `div` for wrapping text, but using `p` will make more sense yea?

Also, search engines understand, that what does your document contain, say, you use `em` so whatever you style your `em` text as, search engines will get a clue that hey, the word in the `em` is emphasized, so it is important one in the document, could be a keyword perhaps.

It's like you are saying a doctor, that my body is paining, but if you describe which part of your `body` pains, will make easy for the doctor to judge and fix the issue easily.

Thus, with the same logic, if you define the headers of the `table` using `th` would rather make more sense instead of using `td`, will help search engines to know your content in a better way, screen readers to read out the data differently, browsers to display it more appropriately.

---

2) *It then goes on to say that some browsers will render the `th` element differently*

Yes, browsers render text of the `th` element in *bold*

---

3) *the article then advises not to style the TH ourselves*

Well, I won't agree with this at all, you can style the `th` elements

---

4) *I find no mention that the `th` element is depreciated nor can I see any value in it.*

No, they aren't obsolete/deprecated <sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1]. Though, some of the attributes are deprecated for the element, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) for more information.</sup>

Comment: Your explanation about semantics is just excellent, very clear and easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any evidence of some search engine making any distinction between `th` and `td`, for example?

Answer (score 5):

You have partly misunderstood the document cited. In particular, it does not say that you should not style `th`; rather, that you should not use `th` for just “styling”, i.e. use it for something that is not a table header, just to make it appear bold and centered. (This warning isn’t particularly relevant; I haven’t ever seen people do such things.)

By definition, `th` contains header information for cells. This is rather vague, but in many simple case, it is rather obvious and simple – typically so that the first row of a table contains headers for the columns, like names of quantities.

The practical impact is that special browsers and assistive software may be able to present a table to the user in a much better way, if they know the association between data cells and header cells. For example, when a particular cell is being investigated by the user, they can, instead of just its content like “32 °C”, also indicate the names of the relevant headers, like “Max. temperature” from a column header cell and “Kairo” from a row header cell.

Browsers render `th` element contents in bold face and as horizontally centered by default; this practice is being standardized in HTML5. But this is just to be taken into account; you can override it in CSS if desired. Especially bolding is mostly useful for header cells, making it easier to notice them and recognize them as headers.

There are different minor differences as well, like different sets of allowed attributes (in HTML5).

Answer (score 1):

The [TH](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/th) attribute, according the [W3C](http://www.w3.org), can specify the cell which the influence of headding cell reaches by the scope attribute.

This attribute is important for SEO too. It helps to prioritize the elements of an HTML page.

If you do not want to optimize SEO on your web page : don't use it.

If you want to encode properly respecting the conventions : use it.

But I do not really understand your reasoning. It's like says :

> Why the [STRONG](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/strong) tag? There's already a [SPAN](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span) tag and we can style it in CCS with "*font-weight:bold*" !

But that doesn't make sense because the conventions (such as W3C) established councils describe all the possible page elements so more accurately.
Hence the direction of new HTML5 markup with advantages such as [ADRESS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/address), [SECTION](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section), [ARTICLE](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article), [ASIDE](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside), [NAV](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav), ...